# How to use group by to group multiple columns together and choose the top 1 on rest columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, min

I have a table in MS Sql Server

```
AA   BB   CC   DD
---- ---- ---- ----
a1   b1   c1   d1
a1   b1   c2   d2
a1   b1   c3   d3
a2   b1   c4   d4
a1   b2   c5   d5
```

The query I want is like this:

If multiple rows with the same AA and the same BB, then only one row of them should be displayed and that row should have the least CC.

Assume c1 < c2 < c3, then The table I want to get is

```
AA   BB   CC   DD
---- ---- ---- ----
a1   b1   c1   d1
a1   b2   c5   d5
a2   b1   c4   d4
```

How do I write this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.AA, A.BB, A.CC, A.DD 
FROM tableA A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT AA, BB, MIN(CC) AS CC 
            FROM tableA GROUP BY AA, BB
           ) B ON A.AA = B.AA AND A.BB = B.BB AND A.CC = B.CC
```

**OR**

```
SELECT AA, BB, MIN(CC) AS CC, MIN(DD) AS DD
FROM tableA 
GROUP BY AA, BB
```

Comment: what if I only care MIN(CC)? and also MIN(CC) will be used with priority?

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with SQL Server 2008 you can use the ROW_NUMBER() function:

```
SELECT aa,bb,cc,dd
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aa,bb ORDER BY cc ASC) r
FROM table;

AA   BB   CC   DD   r
---- ---- ---- ---- --------------------
a1   b1   c1   d1   1
a1   b1   c2   d2   2
a1   b1   c3   d3   3
a1   b2   c5   d5   1
a2   b1   c4   d4   1
```

Use this as a subselect to get your result:

```
SELECT aa,bb,cc,dd FROM (
  SELECT aa,bb,cc,dd
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aa,bb ORDER BY cc ASC) r
  FROM table) q1
WHERE r = 1;
```

If several rows share the same minimum value, the database picks one. In case you want to return them all, replace the ROW_NUMBER() function with RANK().

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1003/2/0)